# dynamic jquery question

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing the following to toggle the display of an element:

```
$("*[id^=" + id + "_]").toggle(); // id is the element to toggle
```

This then toggles everything of the form id_* where * is any string.

I now realized, that I don't want to simply toggle each element, but show or hide it based on the state of the clicked element.  How can I conditionally show() or hide() all those elements of the form 'id_*' depending on some other boolean?  My problem is that the selector automatically selects multple id's, so how I can I trigger a show() or hide() selectively on *each* id that is selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a bool to [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle2) to tell it whether to show and hide, so just look through, like this:

```
$("*[id^=" + id + "_]").each(function() {
  var someBool = condition; //figure out each one here, depending on...whatever
  $(this).toggle(someBool);
});
```